# What happens when departmental tenure and promotion committee falsifies the record?

Tags: tenure-track, promotion

The department I work in has been dysfunctional, and there is a history of reversals of decisions where both yes and no votes were overturned by the university level committee. Very recently, a candidate who went up for promotion to full professor had a mediocre record, and the department T&P committee was trying to push her through. It was found out that they intentionally omitted her lowest teaching evaluation, and when confronted by a senior colleague, a member of the committee tried to lie about it to cover it up (the committee member tried to claim that they ‘sometimes’ drop the lowest and highest, but the evidence clearly shows that only the lowest was dropped). What is the likely outcome, if any?

Update: I should provide some context here. Three of the members on the tenure and promotion committee have pretty weak scholarship (less than what would be acceptable for tenure and promotion based on current standards of the department, but are associate professors though have not published in years). One member was an assistant professor who recently received tenure, but her status is still shaky and needs political support to keep moving forward. The candidate in question has a very close personal relationship with the T&P committee members. The department has substantially dropped in rankings from 15 years ago, where it was in the top 10 in US News to now in the mid-40s. There is talk of a merger with another academic program at the university. Of the faculty who were hired and went up for promotion, the ones voted up by the department were all previous graduates of the school, so there is indication that nepotism is in play. At what point will the upper administration say there is too much dysfunction and step in? What might be done?

Comment: This is too local for a good answer here.

Comment: Send the evidence to the Dean at the highest level - be prepared for consequences...

Comment: @SolarMike Better not to give such advice without knowing the status of OP.  Keep in mind the dictum: "Whoever messes with politics should be prepared for politics messing with them". OP should tread carefully - however, it seems that a "senior colleague" already knows about the matter, so quite possibly OP does not have to expose themselves.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs "be prepared for consequences" What do you think that means?

Comment: Errrm. "Do not meddle in the affairs of wizards".

Comment: It's difficult for me to imagine the point of omitting this one teaching evaluation. If it was way below the others, then there's presumably an explanation that could be given to the higher administration. If it's only slightly below the others, it shouldn't make a difference in the final decision. I'm inclined to suspect that this promotion file contains additional falsifications, enough to make a real difference.

Comment: This is becoming more and more just a rant. As such it is unlikely to be opened.

Comment: Get out while you still can.

Comment: Thank you for all your advice... I am uncertain what will happen, but your comments validated what I sensed in the past few years. I have resigned myself to making the best of the situation for now, focusing on my scholarship and building my professional networks outside my department, so I can have options to leave when the time is right. I am also hoping maybe the department might change when certain people retire, or if there is a major structural change, though that might bring other stressors with it.